# Взаимодействие формы и виджета карты на ней

Tags: c++, qt, yandex-maps-api, qwebengine

Столкнулся с такой задачей как сделать форму, на которой, например, есть два виджета LineEdit и виджет карты (я взял QWebWidget и открыл в нем Яндекс.Карты). Надо вписать два города в строки и получить путь, нарисованный на карте. Также желательна бы и обратная связь: указал на карте города, их названия появились в соответствующих строках формы. Пока нет идей как это грамотно сделать. Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: вроде это называлось `геокодирование` (город -> координаты, координаты -> город). А вот с путём сложнее. Имеется в виду путь по дорогам, или наикратчайшее расстояние по поверхности земли (ортодромия) ?

Comment: @vegorov По дорогам. Кратчайший или нет значения не имеет. Спасибо за уточнение.

Answer (score 1):

[Маршрутизатор Яндекс.Карт](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/router/multiRouter.html) принимает значения в виде адресов и топонимов. Вы можете передавать названия городов из своей кастомной формы ([пример](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_driving)) или использовать готовую Панель маршрутизации ([пример](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/deliveryCalculator/)).

> указал на карте города, их названия появились в соответствующих
> строках формы

Как уже подсказали в комментариях, следует использовать [функцию обратного геокодирования](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/geocode.html) ([пример](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_reverse_geocode))